# Does a photon possess mass?

Tags: particle-physics, photons

One of my friend told me that photon is massless but I think that (please correct me if i was wrong),  Albert Einstein's equation  $E=mc^2$.

This equation stands for energy,  now as we know energy is also, $E= hc/\lambda$ here h is planck constant and c is speed of light and $\lambda$ is wavelenght of upcoming photons wavelenght so from both equation $mc^2 =hc/\lambda$ solving further $m=h/c\lambda$ hence the photon is not massless.

Tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: This question should certainly be closed, but at least some of the alleged duplicates are not duplicates.  They ask "Does a photon have mass?".  This one asks "Why doesn't Einstein's equation imply that a photon has mass?".  That's off topic for multiple reasons, but a very different question nonetheless.

Comment: @WillO Not sure I agree. The answer is "Using $E = mc^2$ as a definition of mass is incorrect, the right definition is...".

Answer (score 1):

The actual relation is $E^2$ = $(pc)^2$ + $(mc^2)^2$  where m is the rest mass of the particle. Photons do not posses rest mass making m zero. Thus $E$ = $pc$ for photons.